# How to find the constexpr max of variable number of constexpr std::arrays with a default value

Tags: templates, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

So, I have a number of `constexpr std::array<int, N>` for various values of `N`. In this case:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 3> r1 {1, 3, 5};
constexpr std::array<int, 2> r2 {3, 4};
constexpr std::array<int, 4> r3 {1, 2, 5, 6};
constexpr std::array<int, 2> r4 {2, 6};
```

What I'd like to do is find the `constexpr` `max` (and subsequently, `min`) element across all of the `array`s. This seems to work just fine:

```
constexpr int the_max() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr int the_max(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) {
    const int v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
    return std::max(v, the_max(ts...));
}
```

As shown here:

```
constexpr auto max_entry = dlx::the_max(r1, r2, r3);
std::cout << max_entry << '\n';
```

which prints 6, as expected.

However, it feels like there should be more logic here, such as:

1. A default (or minimal) value; and
2. That the types across the `std::array` should be able to be different, as long as they are all arithmetic types.

I feel like this should work:

```
template<typename B>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<B>, B>
the_max2(B&& b) {
    return b;
}

template<typename B, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<B> && std::is_arithmetic_v<T::value_type>, std::common_type_t<B, typename T::value_type>>
the_max2(B&& b, T&& t, Ts&&... ts) {
    const int v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
    return std::max(v, the_max2(ts...));
}
```

but it borks out with:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'the_max2<int>(int, const std::array<int, 3>&, const std::array<int, 2>&, const std::array<int, 4>&)'
```

and only expecting 1 parameter but receiving 4, and:

```
 error: 'value_type' is not a member of 'const std::array<int, 3>&'
```

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It seems you forgot the keyword `typename` here `std::is_arithmetic_v<T::value_type>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems, in no particular order

(1) as pointed by S.M., you've forgotten a `typename` before `T::value_type`

```
template<typename B, typename T, typename... Ts> // .......................VVVVVVVV
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<B> && std::is_arithmetic_v<typename T::value_type>, std::common_type_t<B, typename T::value_type>>
```

(2) you've forgotten `b` in recursive calling

```
// .........................V
return std::max(v, the_max2(b, ts...));
```

(3) you have used `int` type for `v` when you should use `auto` (or `typename T::value_type`, if you prefer)

```
// ...VVVV (not int)
const auto v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
```

(4) the "common type" should evaluate also the `Ts::value_type`'s, so

```
// ...........................................VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
std::common_type_t<B, typename T::value_type, typename Ts::value_type...>
```

(5) you should explicit the type for `std::max()`.

```
   using rt = std::common_type_t<B, typename T::value_type, typename Ts::value_type...>;
   // ...
   return std::max<rt>(v, the_max2(b, ts...));
   // ............^^^^
```

(6) I suggest to receive arguments as const pointers instead of rvalues

```
 //..........VVVVVVV......VVVVVVV.......VVVVVVV
 the_max2 (B const & b, T const & t, Ts const & ... ts)
```

The following is a full compiling example (with a simplification to detect only one time the returned common type)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename B>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<B>::value, B>
   the_max2 (B const & b)
 { return b; }


template <typename B, typename T, typename ... Ts,
          typename RT = std::common_type_t<B, typename T::value_type,
                                           typename Ts::value_type...>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<B>::value
                        && std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type>::value, RT>
   the_max2 (B const & b, T const & t, Ts const & ... ts)
 {
   const auto v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
   return std::max<RT>(v, the_max2(b, ts...));
 }

int main()
 {
   constexpr std::array<short, 3> r1 {{1, 3, 5}};
   constexpr std::array<int, 2> r2 {{3, 4}};
   constexpr std::array<long, 4> r3 {{1, 2, 5, 6}};
   constexpr std::array<long long, 2> r4 {{2, 6}};

   auto  m { the_max2(4l, r1, r2, r3, r4) };

   std::cout << m << std::endl;
 }
```

Bonus suggestion: if you can give up the `std::is_arithmetic` test, you don't need recursion and you can write your function simply expanding the variadic template as follows

```
template <typename B, typename ... Ts,
          typename RT = std::common_type_t<B, typename Ts::value_type...>>
constexpr RT the_max3 (B const & b, Ts const & ... ts)
 { return std::max<RT>({b, *std::max_element(ts.cbegin(), ts.cend())...}); }
```

If you can use C++17, instead of C++14, you can use template folding to recover the `std::is_arithmetic` SFINAE test as follows

```
template <typename B, typename ... Ts,
          typename RT = std::common_type_t<B, typename Ts::value_type...>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<
     (std::is_arithmetic<B>::value && ...
   && std::is_arithmetic<typename Ts::value_type>::value), RT>
   the_max3 (B const & b, Ts const & ... ts)
 { return std::max<RT>({b, *std::max_element(ts.cbegin(), ts.cend())...}); }
```

Comment: Question for you: is there a reason to prefer `std::is_arithmetic<X>::value` over `std::is_arithmetic_v<X>`?

Thanks for providing the template folding example. I haven't tried template folding yet, and this will be excellent study material for me. (Also, sorry for the stupid bugs I made, and thanks for pointing them out! Eeep!)

Comment: @Sebastian - sorry, the `std::is_arithmetic<X>::value` is a problem of my compiler: is too old and doesn't suppost `std::is_arithmetic_v<X>`.

Comment: For your first bonus suggestion, do you see anything wrong with changing the return type from `RT` to:

`std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<RT>, RT>` ?

That way, I could preserve the is_arithmetic by checking the common type? Or would that be nonsensical?

Comment: @Sebastian - yes: I suppose should works; I see now that is a double SFINAE filter; the first one over the `RT` template type itself, the second one over the returned value; as far I remember I've never done something similar before yesterday (in the C++17 folding case) but I don't see why shouldn't works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the `std::is_arithmetic` trait to the `value_type` of the passing arguments not to themselves, you also need to remove references from template parameters since you're using forwarding references.

using [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)

```
namespace impl {
    template <bool... Preds> struct all_dummy;
    template <bool... Preds> using all = std::is_same<all_dummy<Preds...>, all_dummy<((void)Preds, true)...>>;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<
    impl::all<
        std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::value_type>::value
    >::value,
    typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::value_type
>
the_max2(T&& t) {
    const int v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
    return v;
}


template<typename T, typename... Ts, typename R = 
    std::common_type_t<
            typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::value_type,
            typename std::remove_reference_t<Ts>::value_type...>
>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<
    impl::all<
        std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::value_type>::value,
        std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference_t<Ts>::value_type>::value...
    >::value,
    R
>
the_max2(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) {
    const int v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
    return std::max<R>(v, the_max2(ts...));
}
```

if [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is available the code can be simplified by using `if constexpr`

```
namespace impl {
    template <bool... Preds> struct all_dummy;
    template <bool... Preds> using all = std::is_same<all_dummy<Preds...>, all_dummy<((void)Preds, true)...>>;
}


template<typename T, typename... Ts, typename R =
    std::common_type_t<
        typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::value_type,
        typename std::remove_reference_t<Ts>::value_type...>
>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<
    impl::all<
        std::is_integral_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::value_type>,
        std::is_integral_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<Ts>::value_type>...
    >::value,
    R
>
the_max2(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) {
    const int v = *std::max_element(t.cbegin(), t.cend());
    if constexpr (sizeof...(ts) > 0) {
        return std::max<R>(v, the_max2(ts...));
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice but... this question is tagged C++14; `if constexpr` is available  only from C++17 (with template folding that permit a bigger simplification)

Comment: Sorry. I am absolutely willing to go C++17. I just tagged it 14 since I didn't think I had any 17-specific code in my example.

Comment: @Sebastian - OK; so `if constexpr` is available.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't notice the tag. I fixed it for c++14

Comment: @Jans - No, please: read the OP's comment: he accept C++17 and changed the tag.

Comment: Yes, @max66 is right. I changed it to C++17. This is excellent. I'll upvote / mark the best solution in a couple hours after I play around a bit.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you explain what is happening in the `namespace impl` code? I'm having difficulty understanding what you're doing here: for example, why the `(void)Preds`?

Comment: @Sebastian `impl::all` is only used to expand the pack `Preds` into arguments for `all_dummy` so that you can use it to check if all `Preds` are true, `all_dummy<true, false> != all_dummy<true, true>` check some test [here](https://godbolt.org/z/RfBPRN). the cast `(void)Preds` is just to avoid the warning of unused expressions. notice that the trick of `impl::all` is not really needed in c++17 since you have folding expressions, you can use it the way @max66 did in his answer.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for the explanation, @Jans!